# in R, Is there a way to remove the first and last element of a vector of unknown length, in one command, without using packages?

Tags: r

I have a vector of "yearmon" and I want to strip the first and the last elements of it while creating it.

Kind of smt like this:

```
vec_strp <- seq(start, end, by = "month")[-first, - last]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
#Code
vec_strp <- seq(start, end, by = "month")[-c(1,length(seq(start, end, by = "month")))]
```

Some testing:

```
#Data
start <- as.Date('2020-01-01')
end <- as.Date('2020-12-31')
#Code
vec_strp <- seq(start, end, by = "month")[-c(1,length(seq(start, end, by = "month")))]
```

Output:

```
 [1] "2020-02-01" "2020-03-01" "2020-04-01" "2020-05-01" "2020-06-01" "2020-07-01" "2020-08-01"
 [8] "2020-09-01" "2020-10-01" "2020-11-01"
```

Comment: Thank you very much; still learning R, so I have much to learn ;)

Answer (score 3):

Simple method:

```
vec_strp <- head(tail(seq(start, end, by = "month"), -1), -1)
```